# Lightning Opportunity creation - Looking for expert opinion

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow

We have been working on analyzing the lightning migration project for last few weeks. We have also engaged with Salesforce expert. 
At this point, the lightning platform doesn’t have out of the box capabilities to meet all our basic requirements. At the same time, we do not want to go with a major custom solution.

I am looking for a lightning migration experts direction and guidance on a road blocking issue.
**We are stuck in Opportunity creation business process. Looking for some help here.**

**Current platform Overview:**

- We have 10 different opportunity page layouts, each page represents
  the different business unit.
- Each business unit users have the different profile.
- Every page has around 60% of the fields are common, rest of the 40%
  vary based on business unit.
- Opportunity create page open up from click of a URL button on contact
  page.
- Opportunity page layout is called from URL hacking by passing Account
  ID and Contact ID.

**Lightning platform migration solutions we are currently reviewing are:**

**Solution-1: Create a visual flow and embed in a Visualforce page**

- Visualforce page is called from contact record as an action button.
- Flow’s first page has 60% common fields, when user hits next button
  on the flow, it brings rest of the 40% fields on next screen based on
  logged in user business unit/profile.
- Once opportunity is created, user will be landing to newly created
  opportunity record.
- **Drawback**: I can’t add dependent picklist in flow screen. We have many dependent picklist fields.

**Solution-2: Use Publisher Action**

- It would be out of the box solution, can be implemented with minimal
  effort.
- **Drawback:** We have 10 opportunity page layouts – I may end up creating 10 publisher actions with different page layouts. All 10 publisher action buttons will appear on contact page. **I guess it would be a dumb solution.**
- **Question:** Is there anyway can I hide the publisher action button based on the profile ?. So that user won’t see all 10 publisher action buttons on contact page?

**As a third Solution:** You may suggest that create one publisher page with common 60% fields, rest of the 40% fields, ask users to enter while updating the opportunity. We do not want to go with this approach.

Can you please recommend any other alternatives ?

Comment: Would that be an issue if they have to choose the contact manually? You should simply use out of the box functionality and create an opportunity from Account Detail Page in Related List. If you have multiple business processes, it will prompt the Record type selection page before creation. After you also could use Contact Roles which is another out-of-box functionality in Opportunity Related List. Would you sacrifice so much development just to save one click ? It's just my point of view but it's simply reeducating the sales reps the real challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is the existing process running last 4 years, user clicks 'new opportunity' button on contact,  when it landed to opportunity page - contact role and account is already there.  We donot have different record type for profile.